# Django migration returns unexpected name

Tags: python, django

I am trying to migrate a database, but every time I try it returns the error below. My app name is 'helloservice', but the table is 'customer' in the database 'pulse'. How do I tell Django not to use the helloservice prefix?  If needed I followed a tutorial [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/), and am now trying to adapt the results to my own needs.

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'pulse.helloservice_customer' doesn't exist")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Meta class and set table name. Then the table name only set customer. It does not use prefix(app name). Then make migrations and set migrate.

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_email = models.EmailField()
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ccustomer_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    customer_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "customer"
```